# How to grow/shrink widely a container's width based on scroll till it reaches top of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, storybook

My code is working at some extent like for medium screens it looks good, but for bigger screens like 1920*1080, I can see much gap at left and right side even Im very close to the top of the screen. When top reaches, it suddenly fills the right and left gap. For small screens like small laptops and tabs, I can see the container's width occupies 100% width before even reaching top of the screen. Below is my implemented code, please suggest some solution.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Template = () => {
const [scrollPercentage, setScrollPercentage] = useState(0);
const [isAtTop, setIsAtTop] = useState(false);

const isMobileView = window.innerWidth < 768;

const handleScroll = () => {
const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
const percentage = (scrollPosition / window.innerHeight) * 100;
setScrollPercentage(percentage);

const expandableContainerTop = document.querySelector(".expandable-         container").getBoundingClientRect().top;
setIsAtTop(expandableContainerTop <= 0);
};

useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
};
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
if (isAtTop) {
  alert("Media container reached the top of the screen!");
}
}, [isAtTop]);

const calculateWidth = () => {
const baseWidth = isMobileView ? 100 : 80;
const maxScrollPercentage = 20;
const dynamicWidth = isAtTop ? 100 : baseWidth + Math.min(scrollPercentage * 0.3,                                                               maxScrollPercentage);
return `${dynamicWidth}vw`;
};

return (
<div className="shoaib-rebrand">
  <section className={`one-col-container column-container is-expandable`}>
    <div
      style={{
        marginBottom: "200px",
        background: "linear-gradient(to top, #FFF 0%, #FFF 10%, #2A5B6C 10%, #2A5B6C 100%)",
      }}
    >
      <div
        className={`${isFluid ? "fluid-container" : "container"} pt-${topPadding} pb-$.  {bottomPadding}`}
        style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
      >
        <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div className={`col-${isMobileView ? 12 : col}`}>
            <div className="text-center pb-6 pt-6 inverse-color">
              <h1> This is the header title</h1>
              <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum
                available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some
                form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't
                look even slightly believable.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          {isExpandable && (
            <div
              className={`expandable-container col-${expandableCol} ${scrollPercentage}`}
              style={{
                width: calculateWidth(),
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgray", height: "100%" }}></div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      className="expandable-container"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "lightgray",
        marginTop: "100px",
        height: "1000px",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    ></div>
   </section>
   </div>
);
};
```

export default Template;

Comment: Narrow viewports give it 100% width all the time. Wider viewports give it 100% width when the scroll is at approx 66.666% Is there a reason for not having a linear continuous width from 0 to 100 whatever the width of the viewport?